# Flutter Webview lock go back on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am writing a project in Flutter. It has only one main page, which has a webview (*flutter_inappwebview*).

When you swipe from the left side of the screen, i need to lock the function to "Go back" on iOS devices.

I tried to use *willPopScope* but it didn't help because there is only one page in the application's router.

**Code example:**

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

*my_app.dart*

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appName,
      home: const MainView(),
    );
  }
}
```

main_view.dart

```
class MainView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        print('not to go back');
        
        return false;
      },
      child: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://google.com')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this `WillPopScope(onWillPop: () async => false,`

Comment: I used WillPopScrope in the above example, it doesn't work with flutter_inappwebview

Comment: Try the other one if that also doesn't works then there's another way to block it from native swift code

Answer (score 0):

You can block the navigation by either using

```
WillPopScope(onWillPop: () async => false,
```

or

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://google.com')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If this also doesn't works for you then edit your AppDelegate.swift and add this code after launchingOptions)

```
let controller: FlutterViewController
    = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController;
controller.navigationController?
    .interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false;
```

This will block the gestures navigation in your ios app. Note this is a bad approach if you have multiple screens in your app but if you have only screen then its fine

Comment: Print in my WillPopScope doesn't call

Comment: Updated answer try now